# how do i get the content of a returning value?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am working on a Phonegap app for a while now, i am using this plugin to download files from the server to the Documents/ forder on the device:

https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-simplefilemanagement

i tested the plugin and it works. it downloads the file and it also reads the file.

```
// READ A FILE
c.read_file('data/','content.json',Log('file contents: '),Log('something went wrong'));
```

painlessfs.js does something:

```
this.read_file = function(dir, filename, success, fail){
    // console.log(dir);
    fail = (typeof fail == 'undefined')? Log('FileManager','read file fail'): fail;
    this.load_file(
        dir,
        filename,
        function(fileEntry){
            fileEntry.file(
                function(file){
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

                        success(evt.target.result);
                    };

                    reader.readAsText(file);
                }, 
                fail
            );

        },
        fail
    );
};
```

I get this log back:

```
Oct 22 15:12:00 Iphone-van-patrick A12 VEG[10479] <Warning>:  file contents: :
Oct 22 15:12:00 Iphone-van-patrick A12 VEG[10479] <Warning>:        {"data":[{"Id":"1","C_Code":"Frontpage_Title","C_output":"A12-VEG"},{"Id":"2","C_Code":"Frontpage_Welkom","C_output":"Welkom A12-VEG"},{"Id":"3","C_Code":"Frontpage_intro","C_output":"hiiii"}]}
```

it works well as jou can see... but what i want is i need to bind the "file contents" to for example "FileContent"

what i have tried is this:

```
// READ A FILE
c.read_file('data/','content.json',FileContent(evt.target.result),Log('something went wrong'));

Function FileContent (Content){
console.log(Content);
}
```

i want to return the content of the file.

can somebody look at it and help me with this?

**EDIT:** 
so i found out that: "evt.target.result" holds the content of the file and returns it to "success". but how do i get this data out of "success"??

Answer (score 0):

You do like this :

```
c.read_file('data/','content.json', function(r) { console.log(r) }, Log('something went wrong'));
```